# Understanding copy constructors and assignment operators with an example

Tags: c++

I've been reading the book "An Introduction to Design Patterns in C++ with Qt 4" recently and I am confused by the following example (codes are from the book, with a small modification by myself):

"fraction.h"

```
class Fraction
{
public:
    Fraction(int n, int d): m_Numer(n), m_Denom(d) {
        ++ctors;
    }

    Fraction(const Fraction& other)
        : m_Numer(other.m_Numer), m_Denom(other.m_Denom) {
        ++copies;
    }

    Fraction& operator = (const Fraction& other) {
        m_Numer = other.m_Numer;
        m_Denom = other.m_Denom;
        ++assigns;
        return *this;
    }

    Fraction multiply(Fraction f2) {
        return Fraction (m_Numer*f2.m_Numer, m_Denom*f2.m_Denom);
    }

    static void report();

private:
    int m_Numer, m_Denom;
    static int assigns;
    static int copies;
    static int ctors;
};
```

"main.cpp"

```
#include <iostream>
#include "fraction.h"
using namespace std;

int Fraction::assigns = 0;
int Fraction::copies = 0;
int Fraction::ctors = 0;

void Fraction::report()
{
    cout<<"[assigns: "<<assigns<<", copies: "<<copies<<", ctors: "<<ctors<<"]\n\n";
}

int main()
{
    Fraction twothirds(2, 3); // It calls a constructor
    Fraction threequarters(3, 4); // It calls a constructor
    Fraction acopy(twothirds); // It calls a copy constructor
    Fraction f4 = threequarters;  
    // [Question A]: The book says it's using a copy constructor 
    //               but I don't see how. Isn't it an assignment?

    cout<<"after declarations\n";
    Fraction::report();  //output: [assogns: 0, copies: 2, ctors: 2]

    f4 = twothirds;  // It's an assignment using the assignment operator
    cout<<"before multiply\n";
    Fraction::report();  //output: [assogns: 1, copies: 2, ctors: 2]

    f4 = twothirds.multiply(threequarters);
    cout<<"after multiply\n";
    Fraction::report();  //output: [assogns: 2, copies: 3, ctors: 3]
    // [Question B]: How does the frunction "multiply" creates three Fraction objects?

    return 0;
}
```

As the comments I left in `main.cpp`, I got 2 questions.

[Question A]: Why `Fraction f4 = threequarters` using copy constructor rather than assignment?

[Question B]: How does the frunction "multiply" creates three Fraction objects?

Especially for Question B, I can't figure out where are those three objects from.

Please help me understanding the concepts. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question A:** Why Fraction f4 = threequarters using copy constructor rather than assignment?

**Answer A:** That is the definition of the C++ language. If you had used

```
Fraction f4;
f4 = threequarters;
```

then the second line would use the assignment operator.

**Question B:** How does the frunction "multiply" creates three Fraction objects?

**Answer B:**

When you call `multiply`, the argument `f2` is created by using copy construction.

The line

```
return Fraction (m_Numer*f2.m_Numer, m_Denom*f2.m_Denom);
```

construct on object using the regular constructor.

The line

```
f4 = twothirds.multiply(threequarters);
```

assigns the object constructed in `multiply` to `f4`.

Comment: Thanks for your detail answers! It's very helpful and shed some light on my original problems. In your Answer A, `Fraction f4;` calls a constructor and `f4 = threequarters;` uses the assignment operator. Now I see why, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Question A: Because in line Fraction f4 = threequarters, f4 doesn't exist yet so copy constructor is called to create a copy of "threequarters". operator= is only called when object already exists (ie. f4 = twothirds)

Question B: Fraction multiply(Fraction f2), when twothirds.multiply(threequarters) is executed, function call parameters are "pass by value" (ie. a copy is passed into the function). So in this instance a copy of "threequarters" is made and passed into "multiply". Then inside that function you explicitly created a Fraction by calling a constructor. Finally you returned this as Fraction which means a copy of it returned. So entire function call made 1 copy constructor call to pass it in, 1 constructor call to create the Fraction and 1 copy constructor call to return the Fraction, total 3.

Comment: Thx! I think I need more deep study on fundamental C++ mechanism.

Comment: Actually I just saw in your report that the multiply only has 1 copy and 1 constructor call. So I guess the compiler must have optimized not having to make a copy when returning because the construction is made on the return statement. You can try declaring a variable in multiply and create a Fraction on it. Then return that variable. See whether a copy is made to return that object.

Comment: There are exactly three Fraction objects created! It's from [1 2 2] to [2 3 3]

Comment: There are no objects created in operator=. Objects are created by constructors only (ie. default, parameterized, copy constructors). So there are only 2 objects created in mutiply according to your report.

Comment: Hmm, I've just did what you said and it gave [2 4 3] (1 assign, 2 copies and 1 constructor) if I explicitly created a new Fraction object and return it.

Comment: Yeah, that is expected because the return value is Fraction so a copy is returned to the caller and the local one is destructed when it goes out of scope (ie after function finishes). Compilers are very smart and does all sorts of optimizations.

Comment: I think I am finally able to assimilate what've you said. Thank you for this helpful lesson!

Comment: You're welcomed. It stumped me also when I saw you only had 1 copy constructor and 1 constructor call in the mutiply() function. So the compiler decided to just create the object on the return address on the stack thereby bypassing the need to create a copy. But when you created a local variable, that changes things and a copy is needed.